# AngularJS Route Not Displaying

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting into Angular JS, and am having a bit of a an issue with routes not displaying. Here's the index file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="backupApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <base href="some/subdiretory/">

    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.10/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.10/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.10/angular-route.min.js"></script>

    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/controllers.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/1.4.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="backupApp">
    <div ng-view class="view-frame">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's my app.js. In one file, as I was debugging:

```
var backupApp = angular.module('backupApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'backupControllers'
]);

backupApp.config(['$routeProvider',
    function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            controller: 'IndexCtrl'
        });
    }
]);

backupApp.controller('IndexCtrl', ['$location', '$window',
    function($location, $window) {
        console.log('hi');
        debugger;
        if ($window.sessionStorage.loggedin) {
            $location.path('/backups');
        } else {
            $location.path('/login');
        }
    }
]);
```

The issue is, no redirection occurs. Not errors are throw. The console.log never displays. I can't figure out what's wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Does adding a template to your route provider def for `/` fix it? eg. `template: '<div></div>'`

Comment: I tried adding a template with both `<div></div>` and `<div ng-controller="IndexCtrl">Helllo World!</div>`. Neither worked :/

Comment: What url are you trying to load initially? Does you need the `/` to be explicit? i.e. `mydomain.com/#/` vs just `mydomain.com`?

Comment: Oh, wow! Found the answer, will post below.